# 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'where' Python

Tags: python-3.x, comparison, where-clause

I need to check if an employee has checked out during the break.
To do so, I need to see if there is the **time** in which `Door Name` is `RDC_OUT-1` **is in the interval [12:15:00 ; 14:15:00]**

```
import pandas as pd

df_by_date= pd.DataFrame({'Time':['01/02/2019 07:02:07', '01/02/2019 10:16:55', '01/02/2019 12:27:20', '01/02/2019 14:08:58','01/02/2019 15:32:28','01/02/2019 17:38:54'],
 'Door Name':['RDC_OUT-1', 'RDC_IN-1','RDC_OUT-1','RDC_IN-1','RDC_OUT-1','RDC_IN-1']})



df_by_date['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_by_date['Time'])
df_by_date['hours']=pd.to_datetime(df_by_date['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S').apply(lambda x: x.time())
print('hours \n',df_by_date['hours'])

out = '12:15:00'
inn = '14:15:00'
pause=0
for i in range (len(df_by_date)):
    if (out < str((df_by_date['hours'].iloc[i]).where(df_by_date['Door Name'].iloc[i]=='RDC_IN-1')) < inn)  :
        pause+=1
        print('Break outside ')
    else:
        print('Break inside')
```

When running the code above, I got this error:

```
if (out < ((df_by_date['hours'].iloc[i]).where(df_by_date['Door Name'].iloc[i]=='RDC_OUT-1')) < inn)  :
```

> AttributeError: 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'where'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are iterating the **DataFrame/Series** you are selecting one cell at a time.

The cell which you are Selecting is of type `datetime.time`

However, `where` only works with the complete **DataFrame/Series** rather than having this in a loop.

Like,

`sub_df = df_by_date['hours'].where(condition)`

and then to count you can use `len(sub_df)`